# Slumdog millionaire (14)

Tags: knowledge

My Indian friend Jamal recently participated in the well-known TV quiz
show ***[Who wants to be a millionaire?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire)***. You might have heard or read about Jamal's spectacular success; the media reported on it extensively.

Here is what Jamal told us about the 500.000 Euro question:

> For the 500.000 Euro question, I excluded answers A and B right away: A is 
>   the smallest of the eight, and does not have any of its own. Furthermore
>   I recalled that B has two in fear and terror. Hence I had to decide myself 
>   between C and D. I was really stumped, so that meant I was going to have 
>   to use my phone-a-friend lifeline.  Fortunately, my friend Albert knows 
>   the weirdest things in the strangest sub-areas of science, and so this seemed
>   to be the right question for him.
>
> I read off the question to him, and only told him answers C and D.  There
>   were a few seconds of silence, and I was afraid that the phone connection
>   had broken down.  Then suddenly Albert's voice came back and told me that
>   D is no good since those are all water deities, whereas the one in the
>   question is "as you like it" and might well belong to C.
>
> "How sure are you?" I probed.  "About nine..." and the phone hung up.
>   I was pretty sure he was going to say ninety-something, which was good
>   enough for me. I happily smiled at Prem and said: "In the 250.000 Euro
>   question I chose for answer C, and also this time I will go for C!". 
>   Prem gave his usual "Are you sure?", and I moved on to the final question. 
>   Good to have Albert as a friend.  Gosh, that's much better than good!

***What was the 500.000 Euro question?

What were the four possible answers A, B, C, D?***

Comment: it might be about biology...coz some [water deities of greek mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_water_deities#Greek_mythology) sound like name of cells... :/

Comment: I am 99% sure that it is about Greek Mythology and its categorizations (water, earth, etc)

Comment: @Oray seems like both of us were totally wrong... :D :p

Comment: @manshu I said 99% :P

Comment: @Oray YAY!!! even i added the word 'might'.. :p

Comment: Nice one. Obviously an English speaker would have used different words which would have made the puzzle too obvious.

Comment: And the sad part is that only one question is left of this series... :(

Comment: You never finished this series (unless you named the last one differently).

Comment: I agree with @wythagoras : these puzzles are excellent, and it is frustrating that we cannot find the final "Slumdog Millionaire (15)" if you have created it !

Comment: AFAIU, those are not "all **water** deities", those are deities that have something in common, but which is not related to water...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The question is:

> Which planet has a moon named Rosalind?
>
> A. Mercury
> B. Mars
> C. Uranus
> D. Neptune

Explanation:

> Mercury is the smallest of the eight planets and doesn't have any moons. Mars has two moons, named Phobos ("Fear") and Deimos ("Terror"). The moons of Uranus are named after Shakespeare characters, and Neptune's moons are named after water deities. Rosalind is a character from Shakespeare's play, "As You Like It", so it is a moon of Uranus.

Comment: Also the one you give is the *only* one that's "as you like it", which is how you can be sure the question was specifically that and not some other name.

Answer (score 11):

The question is something like:

> Which planet has several moons named aftercharacters in Shakespeare's plays including 'As You Like It'

Answer A:

> Mercury -- the smallest planet. Has no moons

Answer B:

> Mars -- Two moons - Phobos(terror/fright) and Deimos (fear)

Answer C:

> Uranus -- The moon Rosalind's name was in the 'As You Like it' and Portia , Juliet, Desdemona...

Answer D:

> Neptune -- All its moons named after gods are water gods

Source: http://www.fief.org/kathleen/Moons/Moons.html

Comment: Darn, f" beat me to the idea, but I feel my answer is more complete (why I took so long), so I'll keave it.